# Database query not returning as expected php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi I am trying to query a database using pdo in php to return all of the information in my database, I am connecting properly to the database however when I try to return all of the database information and print it I get this result returned from my function >

PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM users )

I would like for the function to return the entire database information. Here is my code, your help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
  public function resetpassword() 
  {

         try
         {
            $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); 
            $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';

            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            return $result;

            $conn = null;
         }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            return 'Database Error';
        }

     }
```

here is the code I use to print the results from that function:

```
print_r ($usr->resetpassword());
```

Comment: You first create your database connection in the `resetpassword function`? Or are you creating it in each function? Also you actually have to fetch the results, you can't return the select query.

Comment: Try [`return $result->fetchall();`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) instead of `return $result;`

Comment: That `$conn = null;` will never get executed. But that does not make a difference anyway, since it is a local variable anyway...

Comment: Thanks @Sean that seems to return the entire database now, I will accept yours as answer as you posted it first thank you. Any chance you could explain why the way I was doing it was not printing the entire database please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$result is result set as PDOStatement object. If you use `fetchAll()` it will fetch data as an array of data. Although you can loop through PDOStatement object result set and extract data. Like this:

```
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
 echo $row['yourColumnName'];
}
```

Try this:

```
    <?php

    class Database{

    public function resetpassword() 
      {

             try
             {
                $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); 
                $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';

                $s = $conn->query($sql);

                return $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $conn = null;
             }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                return 'Database Error';
            }

        }

    }

    $usr=new Database();

    var_dump($usr->resetpassword());
```

Comment: answers are always better if there is more detail than just `Try this:` and a code block. Share why this is different than the OPs code. I see what you did, but others may not.

Comment: As stated in the above comment, remove `$conn = null` as the `return` statement will stop it from executing.